# Laptop does not suspend when lid is closed

Tags: power-management

I'm a new Ubuntu 13.10 user. Closing the lid of my laptop does not result in the computer entering suspend mode, meaning each time I close my lid without manually suspending the computer the battery dies.

The proper settings are set in Power Management -- suspend the laptop on lid close for both AC and DC, but these do not have an effect on actual behavior.

It looks like this is a common problem for many users as far back as Ubuntu 11 -- the only solution I could find is the below. However, as a new linux user I'm not aware of how to actually execute the instructions. If someone could provide additional detail that would be tremendously helpful.

Thanks in advance.

```
/etc/acpi/events/lidbtn triggers /etc/acpi/lid.sh which triggers
 /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post at the end of the script.
 /etc/acpi/local/* allows you to add your own config (e.g. required for
 wmii).

 generate /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post
 make it executable and add:

 \#!/bin/bash
 grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
 if [ $? = 0 ]
 then
 /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
 fi

 wmii will now go to suspend mode when closing the lid. It'll
 automatically wake up when opening the lid.
    #!/bin/bash

    load=$(cat /sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/capacity)
    min_load=20
    if [ $load <= min_load ]; then
        pm-suspend
    fi
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

(Note that `#` before a command indicates that it should be run by the superuser, so replace the `#` with `sudo`.)

Open `logind.conf` as root: `# vim /etc/systemd/logind.conf` and remove the `#` before `HandleLidSwitch=suspend`. You can also change the option `suspend` to `hibernate` or `poweroff`

Fix from [Launchpad Bug #863834, comment #30](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/863834#30):

1. Open a terminal: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>
2. `# mkdir /etc/acpi/local`
3. `# vim /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post`
4. Copy this short script:

   ```
    #!/bin/bash
    if grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
    then
        /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
    fi
   ```

   ... and paste it into vim by typing: <kbd>"+p</kbd>
5. Save by typing <kbd>ZZ</kbd> (in capitals)
6. `# chmod 755 /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post` (so it works even when power management is handled under the logged-in user instead of root)

Comment: ps: if you are not sure how to use vim then replace it with gedit and sudo with gksu

Comment: Meow, thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately I'm still not 100% clear. Do I enter these commands in terminal? When I type 'sudo vim /etc/systemd/logind.conf', I get the error 'sudo: vim: command not found'. I'm also on a PC running linux, if that makes a difference.

Comment: use  sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf  if vim is not installed  &  yes you need to enter them in the terminal

Comment: Hrm still does not work. No change on lid close after restart.

    '#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
    #HandleSuspendKey=suspend
    #HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
    HandleLidSwitch=suspend'

Comment: then try this install "dconf-tools" and then type dconf editor in dash or "dconf-editor" in terminal now navigate "org >> gnome >> settings-daemon >> plugins >> power" change lid-close ac action and dc action to suspend("sudo apt-get install dconf-tools" to install it in the first plase)

Comment: reply back if it worked or not(curious :) )

Comment: Bummer, doesn't work :/. I also tried resetting all the settings to default, and checking 'lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor' (even though no external monitor is currently attached). I also noticed when I booted to my windows partition today that the proper behavior (suspend on lid close) no longer works there either.

Comment: It looks like the last resort might be comment #30 here -- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/863834, any idea how to implement these instructions?

Comment: m going to edit my answer with those instructions

Comment: Thanks Meow. Unfortunately this doesn't work either, but since you have answered my original question (how to instructions) I have selected your post as the answer. I dug into the issue further and it looks like this is a kernel bug, which explains why lid close no longer works in Windows either. It looks like it's an issue with my laptop (Samsung Series 5 Ultra), and has been documented here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=45461 as well as several other places.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add the following: `sudo chmod 755 /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post`

Comment: This did not work for me.  But I did not find a script which was mentioned in the beginning of this question.  called acpi/lid.sh

Answer (score 5):

In response to this post, I have had the same problem with this on my Toshiba Satellite a305-s6902 (which I purchased solely to practice on Linux), and found that this worked for me:

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

then as above, remove the `#` before `HandleLidSwitch=suspend` and save (<kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd>).

HOWEVER --->  I find that I must put the computer into suspend manually FIRST, and after every reboot to engage the trigger.  I do not know why, but this has worked consistently for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've solve it by uncommenting variable `LID_SLEEP=true` from `/etc/default/acpi-support`.

Comment: this variable isn't available in 16.04

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.2. Since it's based on Ubuntu 14.04 I expect many things are much the same.

Having searched the suspend on lid closed problem I found myself here and up until then, the best I had come up with was to manually suspend the first time after a boot and afterwards the closed lid would suspend. Having read through these posts and comments I believe I've resolved the issue.

Here's what I did:

1. Opened a terminal session and, using nano instead of vim, typed;

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/systemd/logind.conf
   ```
2. As suggested, I removed the # before `HandleLidSwitch=suspend`. Then I saved it.
3. Then I typed...

   ```
   mkdir /etc/acpi/local
   sudo nano /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post
   ```

   ...and copied and pasted the next 5 lines previously posted

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   if grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
   then
       sudo /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
   fi
   ```

   NOTE: To make this work I added the `sudo` to the line `/usr/sbin/pm-suspend`. Otherwise it would not run.
4. Finally I saved it and as previously posted, typed;
   the logged-in user instead of root, typed;

   ```
   sudo chmod 755 /etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post
   ```

Unfortunately, this did not work. I did some tests, however, on the commands in the script and they did work so I decided something else wasn't triggering them. Further down the posts I came across a reference to a Gnome power manager bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/upower/+bug/863834

Particularly interesting was a post by Michael Backhaus on 2012-06-09 in which he wrote:

> `/etc/acpi/events/lidbtn` triggers `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` which triggers `/etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post`.

Following this was an almost identical version of the above bash script, `lid.sh.post`.

In this version of Mint, `/etc/acpi/events/lidbtn` and `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` did not exist. However, `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn` and `/etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh` did. A look at "powerbtn" provided an answer

This is my work-around:

1. To create a custom "lidbtn", typed;

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn
   ```

   and modified it to like this for lidbtn;

   ```
   # /etc/acpi/events/lidbtn
   # This is called when the user closes the lid and calls
   # /etc/acpi/lidbtn.sh for further processing.

   # Optionally you can specify the placeholder %e. It will pass
   # through the whole kernel event message to the program you've
   # specified.

   # We need to react on "button lid.*" and "button/lid.*" because
   # of kernel changes.

   event=button[ /]lid
   action=/etc/acpi/lidbtn.sh
   ```
2. I saved it. Then copied `/etc/acpi/local/lid.sh.post` to `/etc/acpi/` and renamed it `lidbtn.sh`.

I rebooted and now closing the lid always suspends my laptop. However, I have to manually wake it up when opening the lid. Next project to work on.

ADDENDUM: I should add that I do not have a second monitor. For me, the problem was that suspend simply did not work when the lid was closed.

Comment: Did this work for Linux Mint 18 "Sarah"?
And @bob-el did you find out the workaround for wake up as well?

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the **lid close is handled different when an external monitor is connected**. So changing that option  as user in `dconf-editor` solved the problem for me:

Schema:

```
org.cinnamon.settings-daemon.plugins.power
```

or (depending on what desktop environment you use)

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power
```

Name:

```
lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor
```

Set to:

```
true
```

Description:

> With no external monitors plugged in, closing a laptop's lid  will
>   suspend the machine (as set by the lid-close-battery-action and
>     lid-close-ac-action keys).  By default, however, closing the lid when
>     an external monitor is present will not suspend the machine, so that
>   one can keep  working on that monitor (e.g. for docking stations or
>   media viewers).  Set this     key to False to keep the default behavior,
>   or to True to suspend the laptop whenever the     lid is closed and
>   regardless of external monitors.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mint 18.1 on Macbook Air 6,2. Here is the solution I have and it works nearly perfect.

I use [mba6x_bl](https://github.com/patjak/mba6x_bl) to fix my MBA black screen when waking up. [Follow their instructions](https://github.com/patjak/mba6x_bl).

Then use Bob-El's solution above to solve suspend problem.

- backup and open /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn
      sudo cp /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn_bak
      sudo nano /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn
- replace contents of powerbtn with text below

  ```
  # /etc/acpi/events/lidbtn
  # This is called when the user closes the lid and calls  
  # /etc/acpi/lidbtn.sh for further processing.  
  # Optionally you can specify the placeholder %e. It will pass  
  # through the whole kernel event message to the program you've  
  # specified.  
  # We need to react on "button lid.*" and "button/lid.*" because  
  # of kernel changes.  
  event=button[ /]lid  
  action=/etc/acpi/lidbtn.sh
  ```
- create `/etc/acpi/lidbtn.sh`

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/acpi/lidbtn.sh
  ```
- place the following text into it

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  if grep -q closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state
    then
    /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
  fi
  ```
- Open **Power Management -> On AC Power -> Actions -> When laptop lid is closed**, choose **Blank screen**. This will keep MBA suspend when connecting to power.

The only problem I have noticed is when MBA suspended **with power connected**, its keyboard light will be automatically on. But other than that, everything works well.