# My Laptop doesn't suspend at all in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: suspend

My laptop is Asus N56-jk, I'm an ubuntu 14.04 user, when I push the suspend button or close the lid, it just get locked or somethng like logging out, what should I do?

Comment: First of all try to run "sudo pm-suspend" in terminal. Does laptop suspend?

Comment: No, It didn't, The screen went just for a second then came back.

Comment: There must be some problem with acpi. Upgrading bios may help.

Comment: How can I do that? How can I make it sleep instead of suspending?

Comment: Try http://askubuntu.com/questions/395428/laptop-does-not-suspend-when-lid-is-closed