# Laptop doesn't suspend when lid is closed - No state change

Tags: 14.04, suspend, laptop, power-management, acpi

I have a problem about my laptop that doesn't suspend when i close lid. First the story.

I bought a new **Acer e3-112**. It camed with win8.1 and i upgraded it to win10. Then i shrinked the hdd and installed **Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64 bit**. Without using Gnone, i installed i3 tile manager. Everything was working. Then one day i opened Gnome and i upgraded with `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

Then left bottom of screen started to blink after every start of pc for 1 minute. When i close the lid pc isn't suspending. I read and try

[Laptop does not suspend when lid is closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395428/laptop-does-not-suspend-when-lid-is-closed)

and realized that `/proc/acpi/button/lid/*/state` is alwasy `open`. `pm-suspend` command working well but i think acpi doesn't realize that lid closed.

What can i do for this?