# Laptop not properly suspending after I close lid

Tags: 14.04, suspend, laptop, power-management, battery

Dell Inspiron 3542. When I close my laptop lid and put it in my bag, I often take it out later to find it extremely hot and with the battery drained. I also often find that my monitor turns on immediately after opening the lid again if the battery isn't drained. My system setting are configured so that my laptop is supposed to suspend when I close the lid.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Suspension is not hibernation, the battery is still used to maintain the data in RAM. The fact that it is hot it might be because your hardware does not support well the default Ubuntu suspension system and so some peripherals are not completely shut down. What exactly is your hardware in use? If you suspend manually with `sudo pm-suspend` do you experience the same problems? If you take care of switching off the wi-fi and waiting for the disk to stop writing before suspending, do you have the same issues?

Comment: I ran `sudo pm-suspend` and typed my password, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I have/had the same problem and found this link helpful.
[Laptop does not suspend when lid is closed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395428/laptop-does-not-suspend-when-lid-is-closed)

Like one of the people with "solutions", I found that I have to manually suspend my laptop initially before closing the lid on subsequent occasions will work.

Good luck with it.