# Laptop doesn't suspend after closing lid

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, laptop, power-management, xfce

None of the solutions on here have worked for me. Recently I've installed Lubuntu. I'm getting used to DE (switched from GNOME), however, I have a problem with the power management (Lubuntu uses xfce4 power manager). The system does not suspend after closing lid of my laptop (fan is still working, music is still playing) although I have an "operation after closing the laptop" option set for "suspend" in xfce4-power-manager.

Any suggestion to get this fixed is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide links to the answers you have tried so we don't suggest the same things

Comment: What happens if you run the command `sudo pm-suspend`?  If you don't have pmutils installed, install with `sudo apt-get install pmutils`.  And what happens if you run `sudo systemctl suspend`?  Do either of these methods make your laptop suspend and resume properly?

Comment: @Dorian-  both of them are shutting off my screen but nothing else (fan is still working) and both of them make me restart my laptop (I can't unsuspend it).----                                                                                                                                  Tim I've tried to uncomment lines in some config file (can't remember which one), also downloading some "laptop tools" package and writing a "pm-suspend" script but like I said it didnt help

Comment: @Tim basically everything from this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/395428/laptop-does-not-suspend-when-lid-is-closed